# Call google TTS Cloud API on Android

Tags: android, cloud, text-to-speech

I know the TTS API library is available offline on Android. But how can I use google's online API? I found this code for iOS:

```
local ttsUrl=string.format("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=%s&q=%s", "en", textToSend)
local ttsData = NSData:dataWithContentsOfURL(NSURL:URLWithString(ttsUrl))
local avPlayer = AVAudioPlayer:initWithData_error(ttsData, nil)
avPlayer:play()
```

Basically, what's the best way to send URL, receive the audio, and play it on Android?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok apparently it was as easy as using the Android *MediaPlayer* and passing the URL to *setDataSource(String path)*. Cheers!